# Setting the /home partition in a drive through a LAN

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive, home-directory, external-hdd

I want to install Ubuntu and I would like to set my /home partition in an external USB hard drive that is directly connected to my router, and access my data through the LAN connection. Can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

*Executive summary: Yes, you can do this, but it will not work very well, because the drive probably doesn't support Unix-style permissions.*

You can make your home directory exist on a remote filesystem rather than the local computer. (If you do that, you might want to have another user account, to use for troubleshooting if a problem develops with the remote share.)

However, to work properly, home directories should be on volumes that support [Unix-style file permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions). Your router probably uses SMB/CIFS to share the drive. Such permissions can be exposed well enough through Samba, so if you're using SMB/CIFS (Windows file sharing) to share a drive *that is formatted with a Unix-style filesystem*, this can work (though your router would likely be incapable of that).

The drive probably does not have a Unix-style filesystem. It probably has NTFS, FAT32, exFAT, or (if it's quite small), FAT16. The FAT filesystems don't support any system of permissions at all. NTFS supports permissions, but it's a different system from Unix-style permissions.

So yes, you *can* do this. You can edit `/etc/fstab` and put either `/home` or the specific home directory in `/home` as a mount point to the networks share. But since the volume being shared probably does not support the permissions needed for files inside an Ubuntu home directory, **you probably should not do this.**

A better approach may be to make certain folders inside your home directory (like `Videos`, `Pictures`, `Documents`, `Downloads`, and even `Desktop`) symbolic links to folders in the network share. (Any folder that contains programs or scripts you want to execute should *not* be, though, as it wouldn't be able to have execute permissions.)